# NameError undefined local variable or method 'drink'

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a table listing names of drinks and received the following error. From what I've read, I need to define 'drink' but don't know how to go about that. Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

ERROR
NameError in Wheels#index
undefined local variable or method `drink'

```
<td class="name-container" id="drink<%= index %>" data-id="<%= drink.id%>"><%= drink.name%></td>
```

INDEX.HTML.ERB

```
<table class="drinks-table">
<% @wheel.drinks.each_with_index do |drinks, index| %>
<tr>
  <td class="icon-container0"><i class="fa fa-star"/></td>
  <td class="name-container" id="drink<%= index %>" data-id="<%=    
  drink.id%>"><%= drink.name%></td>
</tr>
```

<% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change `do |drinks, index|` to `do |drink, index|`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo? In your each loop you're calling `|drinks, index|`. Should it be `|drink, index|` ?